# помогите с решением задачи(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача: https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=385

```
import math

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __copy__(self):
        point = Point(self.x, self.y)
        return point

    def distance(self, other):
        r_x = (self.x - other.x) ** 2
        r_y = (self.y - other.y) ** 2
        dist = math.sqrt(r_x + r_y)
        return dist

n = int(input())

a = []
for i in range(n):
    x,y = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    point = Point(x,y)




k = math.sqrt ((x - x) ** 2 + (x  - y) ** 2)
```

1 вопрос:
Не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы из введенных  значение ы цикле, я мог подставить в формулу по расчету расстояния, так как при написание формулы получается из одного и того же значения идет вычитание, из из=за этого не выходит.
2 вопрос:
как посчитать сколько расстояний измерил Дима, тип может формула какая-то или еще что-то

Comment: А где тут «дорешать»? Вижу только класс точки и ввод n точек в одну. Вы код решения забыли приложить?

Comment: Формула у вас уже есть внутри класса, вам нужно использовать её. Читайте координаты, создавайте точки и меряйте расстояние между очередной точкой и предыдущей с помощью метода `distance`

Comment: а как мне начать использовать формулу из класса, можете строчкой кода написать

Comment: Интересно, в этой задаче разные расстояния, которые округляются до одного значения надо считать разными или одним? =)

Comment: @Faymen point.distance(other_point)

Comment: так хорошо, но точка та одна и таже вычитается

Comment: Для точек вам дали список "а" видимо, вначале нужно туда все точки сохранить.

Comment: @RomanR, мне не давали список. Я просто подумал, что так будет лучше, все точки туда записать и потом от этого отталкиваться, но похоже что нет, может можете что-нибудь другое предложить?

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations
from math import sqrt

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def sqr_dist(self, other):
        "Квадрат расстояния - этого достаточно, чтобы отличать разные расстояния между точками"
        return (self.x - other.x)**2 + (self.y - other.y)**2;
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Point {self.x}, {self.y}>'

n = int(input())
# Считываем все точки в массив
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(Point(*[int(x) for x in input().split()]))

# Найденные расстояния складываем в множество, дубликаты отбрасываются автоматически
unique_dists = set()
# Генерируем все комбинации пар точек
for (a, b) in permutations(a, 2):
    # Считаем растояния между точками пары
    unique_dists.add(a.sqr_dist(b))

dists = sorted([round(sqrt(sqr_dist), 9) for sqr_dist in unique_dists])
print(len(dists))
for dist in dists:
    print(dist)
```